# Handling network disconnection on mobile IM app

Tags: android, ios, sockets, java-me, tcpclient

What's the best way to handle and avoid long reconnection time when the network connection is dropped (no signal or telco problem) in an instant messenger-like app? How does XMPP clients handle this or apps like WhatsApp/BBM/Gtalk?

My J2ME app currently opens a socket, keeps it open, and maintains a heartbeat (50secs) + keepalive (20 mins). I must be missing something as BBM and other XMPP clients are more reliable than my app's connection (using the same telco/network).

Wonder if there's also a difference in doing this on Android and iOS.

Comment: heartbeat is coming from the server, not the client